# Permanent feed from light swicth

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch

Here is my question, I want to pull power (Live and Neutral) from a 220 Volts light switch. But my house is wired up like in **FIGURE 1**: (all images referenced below are in 1 image marked as Figure 1, 2, 3 and 4)

[image]

Now what I have noticed is that when the light switch is not switched on, I get a power between point A and point B (**FIGURE 2**) (excuse my horrible drawing :-))

But now when I switch the light switch on, power between point A and point B comes and goes (AC- Alternating Current). All of this I understand and it makes logical sense. Now lets say I have a 220V to 5V charger connected between point A and point B (**FIGURE 2**), the charger would just switch ON and OFF at what ever hertz the power is running at (50-60 HZ). If I had to place a 400V 100uF capacitor (**FIGURE 4**) between point A and point B, would that give just enough power to power the charger for that (working on 50 HZ) 20 milliseconds or am I having the wrong idea here. Or might there be another way to do this? Because I bought a Touch Light Switch from LEAR (looks about the same as **FIGURE 3**) and they are able to work on the way that my lights are connected/wired. Now I have seen 1 or 2 of these exact questions around but people just ask who do they do it. My question is if I place the Capacitor there (**FIGURE 4**), would it help? If anyone could please assist me with a solution for this or even let me know if i am working in the right direction. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please clearly say what you are trying to achieve without clouding your statements with possible solutions, Say what you want then you can rant about this or that afterwards.

Comment: What you are describing makes no sense.  When the switch is on your points A & B are shorted and the light goes on.  When the switch is off, there is power between points A & B only because your lamp completes the circuit.  You cannot power another appliance from points A & B as the voltage will split between the lamp and the appliance and neither will work properly.  The capacitor you show is intended only for DC operation and is complete unsuitable (and unsafe) to use on a 220V AC circuit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to tap off power from that switch, you'll need to tap from "point B" and "N". Then you'll get continuous power, regardless of the light switch's on/off position.

If you connect that electrolytic capacitor in any manner to that light switch circuit, you'll understand with no doubts exactly why you should not do that - your room will instantly be decorated with tinsel and electrolyte from inside the capacitor - electrolytics are really hostile to being connected to municipal power lines.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get power at the switch that is suitable for tapping in to feed off to some other location.

In similar manner, with your current wiring, you cannot deploy a smart type switch that requires a separate neutral connection.

To get power into the switch box in a legitimate manner you will have to string a new wire between the light fixture box and the switch box that contains a black, white, red and GND wire. The black and white will bring power to the switch box and the red would be used to return switched power to the light. Here is a doctored up version of the picture that you linked.

Finally as others have said, please drop the idea of that capacitor. It would explode if you tried attaching it to the power lines.

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael - I stumbled upon your diagram from google images. I have a similar problem, but in reverse. Would this diagram work if the power source is the at the switch box, and but a constantly-powered circuit continues instead from the light box?

Thanks